# Retaining repeating NSTimer for later access?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am creating an NSTimer in the `createTimer` method that I want to refer back to in the later `cancelTimer` method. To facilitate this I am taking ownership of the NSTimer via a retained property so that I can refer back to it later. The issue that is confusing me is, if I start the timer, cancel it and start it again the code crashes.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *walkTimer;
```

.

```
-(void)createTimer {
    NSTimer *tempTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimerDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [self setWalkTimer:tempTimer];
}

-(void)cancelTimer {
    [walkTimer release];
    [[self walkTimer] invalidate];
}
```

Now I seem to have fixed this by changing cancelTimer to:

```
-(void)cancelTimer {
    [self setWalkTimer:nil];
    [[self walkTimer] invalidate];
}
```

I am just curious why release was not working, my understanding was that:

1. NSTimer (Autorelease object, not owned by me)
2. setWalkTimer (takes ownership for me, retainCount+1)
3. release (relinquishes my ownership, retainCount-1)
4. invalidate (lets system dispose of timer)

**EDIT:**

```
// this fails ...
-(void)cancelTimer {
    [[self walkTimer] invalidate];
    [walkTimer release];
}

// this works fine ...
-(void)cancelTimer {
    [[self walkTimer] invalidate];
    [self setWalkTimer: nil];
}
```

**EDIT: 002**

Initially I think I was mixing up

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *walkTimer;
// &
[self setWalkTimer];
```

and thinking that I needed a release to balance the property, I don't I either overwrite it with a new set (either to another object or nil) and finally release the property in dealloc.

Is the property(retain) the same as retain, I would say no, which is where I was going wrong I think.

**EDIT: 003**
With regards to this question I think I personally confused things by wrongly using `[walkTimer release]` As a result the topic drifted to essentially a new question which I have written up as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945028/repeating-nstimer-weak-reference-owning-reference-or-ivar)

Comment: Thank you, so is using [self setWalkTimer:nil]; bad too? The scenario that I am in is that I need to hold a reference to access NSTimer in different methods, I also need to make sure that when I cancel the timer I am not leaking if I start a new one. I guess I could hold a reference just in an iVar and not use a property?

Comment: so in your opinion using a property(retain) to hold the reference is ok? either letting the property manage multiple objects and releasing in dealloc or doing a [self setWalkTimer:nil] ?

Comment: @Joe The doc says, "Note in particular that run loops retain their timers, so you can release a timer after you have added it to a run loop."  You _can_ release the timer doesn't mean you _should_ release it all the time.  If you need to refer to the timer even potentially after it has fired, you need to retain it.

Comment: @Daniel Dickison Can you come up with a situation, where it is actually _preferable_ to have an **owning** reference to an NSTimer? This is an honest question: I am _really_ not seeing one that isn't associated with code smells, but maybe another set of eyes helps.

Comment: @danyowdee The advantage of owning the timer is that it's more consistent with other APIs and Objective-C patterns. In reality, you can do it either way -- if you retain, then don't forget to release as usual; if you don't retain, don't forget to set the pointer to nil so you don't access the timer after it has fired.

Answer (score 4):

You `release` before you call `invalidate`.  That means by the time you call `invalidate`, you've already relinquished ownership of the timer.  In practice, you end up calling `invalidate` on a deallocated timer instance.

What you should do is call `invalidate` *before* you call `release`.  Since you are using a retained property, you can just set the property to `nil`:

```
// Schedule the timer.
self.walkTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWith...];

// Cancel the timer.
[self.walkTimer invalidate];
self.walkTimer = nil;
```

---

#### Update to clear up any confusion regarding memory management

It's important to keep in mind the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) of Objective-C — you own an object if you call `alloc`, `copy` or `retain` on it, and if you own an object, you have to eventually call `release`.  In this case, `setWalkTimer:` retains the timer because the property is declared as `retain` — that means you own the timer and must call `release` on it down the road.  The `invalidate` method does **not** count as relinquishing ownership of the timer.

When you schedule a timer, the run loop retains it, and when the timer fires or is invalidated, the run loop releases it.  But really, you don't need to know that — it's an implementation detail.  The call to `release` by `invalidate` is only to balance the `retain` when the timer was scheduled on the run loop.

Comment: in addition, if you are calling invalidate after you set the property to nil, you're calling `invalidate` on nothing. It won't crash, but it probably isn't the behavior you want.

Comment: @Joe The `NSRunLoop` will retain the timer first. Net effect is 0. `invalidate` is not a substitute for `release`.

Comment: It instructs the NSRunLoop to release the timer, if the NSRunLoop is retaining it. This is independent of the fact that you are retaining the object in setWalkTimer:. You are responsible for releasing that retain yourself. invalidate doesn't do this.

Comment: @Joe It's not surprising at all. The run loop retains the timer when you start it and releases the timer when you `invalidate` it. **If you retain the timer, you must release the timer.**

Comment: is that removes and releases as in "decrements the retain count" or removes and destroys as in "puff gone"?

Comment: Yes, he did retain it. He called the setter of a property declared as retaining.

Comment: And he should retain it. Do not store unretained timers in your ivars. You'll wind up with dangling pointers after they fire. If you needed to keep track of the timer for some reason, then you should retain it. If you don't need to keep track of it, then don't put it in an ivar.

Comment: @Rob Napier I disagree: 1. You do **not** wind up with a dangling pointer after a timer fires! That is only the case when the timer is non repeating (which fuzzygoat's timer isn't). 2. "If you don't need to keep track of it, then don't put it in an ivar" If that were true: How is it then, that the vast majority of delegates in (App|UI)Kit and Foundation are weak references?

Comment: @danyowdee delegates (and datasources which are just renamed delegates) are a very special case because the normal pattern is for the delegate to retain the delegating object. If the object retained the delegate, you would have an retain loop and neither object would ever be released. Experienced Cocoa developers expect anything named "delegate" to be unretained, and behave accordingly. Whether the timer is repeating or not is irrelevant to how you should memory manage it. The fact that you can "get away" with not retaining it in this case does not change best practice.

Comment: "Whether the timer is repeating or not is irrelevant to how you should memory manage it" Where did I claim, that it was relevant? What I **did** (and still do) say is: "don't retain the timer or you build yourself a nice retain-cycle".

Comment: Which (i.e. the retain-cycle), come to think of it again, is totally irrelevant, as it's only temporary...

Answer (score 0):

You need to invalidate before you release. After the timer has fire, you are the only one holding a retain on the timer. So when you call release, the timer deallocates. You then call invalidate on invalid memory and you crash.

Comment: NSTimer does not magically release all retains when it is invalidated. So if you did retain it yourself, you need to release it yourself.

Comment: -1 "After the timer has fire, you are the only one holding a retain on the timer" That is incorrect in the context of the question! Your statement is only true for non-repeating timers.

Comment: @danyowdee, I agree that in this question the timer is repeating, but it does not change best practice here. You should not base your memory management on that fact.

Comment: I just wrote an answer to your comment that I chose to delete because it had a terrible logical flaw in it. I still prefer not having a retain-loop in the first place, but I also see that it only is a temporal issue.

Comment: Where by "temporal" I meant "temporary", of cause.

Answer (score 0):

### <strike>Don't retain a scheduled NSTimer if you've set its target to self</strike> Don't set `self` as the target of a repeating timer unless you are absolutely sure to know all the consequences

(...otherwise the runtime drowns a kitten in leaked timers, targets and userInfos — or so goes the saying.)

Please read and re-read "Overview" in the [NSTimer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-1059) and pay special attention to the last paragraph.

In a nutshell:

1. If you schedule an NSTimer, it becomes associated to the current run-loop which *retains* it.
2. Furthermore, the timer [*retains* its target](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:).
3. `NSTimer` instances are **not reusable**: 
   *"Once invalidated, timer objects cannot be reused"*.

So there is no point in retaining a scheduled timer in the first place.

If you need to hang on to it (e.g. in order to cancel it) use a *non-owning* (aka weak) reference to it.

**Update:**
For a thorough explanation, see [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945028/repeating-nstimer-weak-reference-owning-reference-or-ivar/4946038#4946038) (it now has graphs — albeit as links only — and stuff).

Please consider the rest of this post (as well as many of my comments) as obsolete.

---

Your property becomes

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTimer *walkTimer;
```

BTW:

```
-(void)cancelTimer {
    [self setWalkTimer:nil]; // great, now [self walkTimer] returns nil so
    [[self walkTimer] invalidate]; // here, you are calling [nil invalidate]
}
```

And since messaging nil is absolutely fine in Objective C, your crash miraculously vanishes...while your timer will happily continue to fire.

**Edit**

I've forgot to mention:
A timer wants a selector that takes one argument, which will be the timer that fired... Or is that just a typo?

Comment: Hmm interesting, regarding the weak reference.

Comment: Hi you mean @selector(fireThis:) your right I did miss the ":" for the arg, and the arg off the method -(void)fireThis(NSTimer *)timer; thats just be forgetting to put it in.

Comment: If you use a weak reference to the timer, then you should `[self setWalkTimer:nil]` when the timer fires. Otherwise, a later attempt to cancel will message a dealloc'ed timer and (likely) crash. Having a strong reference is a valid way to do this, though -- you get a retain loop, but the loop will be broken either when the timer fires or it's invalidated.

Comment: Just deleted my previous comment because it had a moronic logical fallacy, here's the new form: You're right, the retain-loop is a non-issue as the timer needs to be invalidated "externally" anyway. From the old comment (though not verbatim): Sure, after invalidating the timer, the reference to it needs to be set to `nil`.