# Method is expected to return an instance of its class type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, class, nstimer

I have an `NSTimer` which is called from a class method to control an `NSProgressBar`. It works seemingly fine on the surface, although I get a warning as I'm using the NSTimer where I'm assuming the compiler wants the class name.

When I put the class name `MyProgressBar` in place of `NSTimer` the warning seems to go away. The reality of the matter is that all hell is breaking loose behind the scenes and the memory allocations start spiking up and up.

The question is, how should this really be done?

.h

```
@interface MyProgressBar : NSProgressIndicator {
    double progressOffset;
    NSTimer* animated;
}

@property (readwrite, retain) NSTimer* animated;
@property (readwrite) double progressOffset;
```

.m

```
- (void)setDoubleValue:(double)value {
    [super setDoubleValue:value];
    if (![self isDisplayedWhenStopped] && value == [self maxValue]) {
        [self stopAnimation:self];
    }
}

- (NSTimer*)animated {   // This is the line with the warning 
    return animated;    // using MyProgressBar ends up creating a memory leak
}

- (void)setAnimated :(NSTimer *)value {
    if (animated != value) {
        [animated invalidate];
        animated = value;
    }
}

- (id)initWithFrame :(NSRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {
        self.progressOffset = 0;
        self.animated = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
```

warning:

```
Method is expected to return an instance of its class type 'MyProgressBar', but is declared to return 'NSTimer *'
Overridden method returns an instance of its class type
```

-> [complete github project here that displays the warning](https://github.com/larcus94/LBProgressBar/archive/master.zip).

Answer (score 1):

The getter should be called `animated`, not `animate`.

Also you should use underscore in all your instance variables (the default pattern) and drop the getter/setter as the compiler will provider better implementations (i.e. that `setAnimated` doesn't look right, if I recollect the use of manual reference counting).  The getter should be returning an `autorelease`d object.

Comment: Yeah, that's my bad on the typo, I did mean animated. Still the same question though - thanks. The original way this was done did release it like you mentioned, although since it's ARC now it's a no-go I assume. [Here's the original method](https://github.com/larcus94/LBProgressBar/blob/master/LBProgressBar/LBProgressBar.m#L44).

Comment: Well I would drop your getter/setter implementations; they are broken.

Comment: @RoryZipher See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936261/retaining-repeating-nstimer-for-later-access) answer.

Comment: Is there one in particular I should pay attention to?

Comment: It makes sense what they're explaining, I thought that using the class name `(MyProgressBar *)` in place of the `(NSTimer *)` and removing the `invalidate` [would been the right way](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3c525d4ce5ae61628732#file-nope-m-L8-L14), but obviously it's far from it. I'm not sure how to do an `autoreleased` object with it...

Comment: @RoryZipher If you are using manual reference counting you need to read-up on it.  If possible use ARC as it's a pain in the ar$e.